# Not able to fetch data using xpath which contains encoded special character

Tags: xml, xpath

Following is my xml structure.

```
<City name="BELLMORE" >
  <SiteName name="MILL POND AUTO BODY" >
    <SiteStreet>3000 Merrick Rd</SiteStreet>
    <ZipCode>11710</ZipCode>
  </SiteName>
  <SiteName name="STS TIRE &amp; AUTO CENTERS" >
    <SiteStreet>CHG Sunrise Hwy</SiteStreet>
    <ZipCode>11710</ZipCode>
  </SiteName>
  <SiteName name="AUTO CONNECTION" >
    <SiteStreet>2860 Sunrise Hwy</SiteStreet>
    <ZipCode>11710</ZipCode>
  </SiteName>
  <SiteName name="PERRY&#39;S AUTO" >
    <SiteStreet>1703 Newbridge Rd</SiteStreet>
    <ZipCode>11710</ZipCode>
  </SiteName>
</City>
```

I am able to find data when I used the following xpath query.

```
//City[@name='BELLMORE']/SiteName[@name='AUTO CONNECTION']/SiteStreet/text()
```

But when I am using following xpath query

```
//City[@name='BELLMORE']/SiteName[@name='PERRY&#39;S AUTO']/SiteStreet/text()
```

It does not return anything. I have converted the special characters in xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath sees the parsed XML, so you need to check for the actual characters rather than the character references:

```
//City[@name="BELLMORE"]/SiteName[@name="PERRY'S AUTO"]
```

XPath string literals can be delimited by single or double quotes, if you want to include a single quote character in the literal then it must be delimited by double quotes.

The thing that muddies the waters somewhat is when you see examples of XPath expressions being used within source code written in another host language such as Java or XSLT, where the characters that make up the XPath expression are subject to the quoting rules of the host language.  For example the above expression in Java might look like:

```java
String xpath = "//City[@name=\"BELLMORE\"]/SiteName[@name=\"PERRY'S AUTO\"]";
```

Or in XSLT it might look like either of:

```
<xsl:value-of select='//City[@name="BELLMORE"]/SiteName[@name="PERRY&apos;S AUTO"]' />
<xsl:value-of select="//City[@name=&quot;BELLMORE&quot;]/SiteName[@name=&quot;PERRY'S AUTO&quot;]" />
```

The expression itself still contains the various single and double quote characters, but how those characters are represented depends on the host language.

Comment: @VimalPatel the only restriction on string literals in XPath 1.0 is that a single-quoted literal can't contain single quotes and a double-quoted literal can't contain double quotes, but apart from that anything goes.  In XPath 2.0 you can escape the delimiting quote type by doubling - the literal `'PERRY''S AUTO'` represents the string `PERRY'S AUTO`, but 1.0 doesn't have an escape mechanism so you have to do tricks with `concat()` if you want to include both types of quote in the same string.